# FreeSync fails in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, tearing with a Radeon video adapter

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, radeon, tearing

My PC has an MSI AMD Radeon RX 580 display adapter, an AMD Ryzen 7 1800X CPU, and an AOC Gaming G2460PF 24" display. The same thing happens on Ubuntu 16.04.4 and Kubuntu 18.04 beta 2: `DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --prop` tells nothing about the FreeSync (from the [AMD's manual](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/HOW-TO-ENABLE-AMD-FREESYNC-IN-LINUX.aspx)), i.e. there are no `freesync_capable` and `freesync` parameters at all. Installing the [AMDGPU-PRO driver](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx) didn't help. Tried on the DP, DVI-D, and HDMI ports.

There is a very strong tearing when just scrolling in Chrome or playing a game (especially on Ubuntu 16.04 which is officially supported by AMD), and the Dota 2 client shows "Failed to initialize Vulkan".

Comment: Which motherboard are you using? How much RAM do you have, and what frequency does it run at?

Answer (score 0):

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --set TearFree on
```

Worked for me with the "scroll tearing".
Hope it helps ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it works for me, xubuntu 16.04.5 with AMD RX 580.
Should highlight that --output parameter may be different, depends where your monitor is connected. To list all available outputs you may run:

```
xrandr
```

In my case it was HDMI 1 port, so command was following:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-1 --set TearFree on
```